How to save data using pygbag and pickle
I have a game which I have ported to browser using pygbag and it works fine while loading the data using pickle but it does not save the data, but when running localy (not on browser) it works fine, how should I save data using pickle or any other saving library with pygbag?
The rest of the game works fine, and it load all assets as well.
The saving code is -
# saving data
file = open("Civ Data/main.pkl", "wb")
pickle.dump(kingdoms, file)
file.close()

If saving the data is not possible then is there a way to give the player a file which they can download and later use to load their save?
the full code is - https://github.com/IGR2020/PaperCiv/tree/browser

it does not save the data what have you done to make sure of that? if there's an error, please post the error message. if not, the data is probably saved.

See this help article about persistent data.

so, in the article it says that local file saving is to be done, so we can save data, also by saving the data I mean it skips the part of the code which saves the data.

To save your object window.localStorage.setItem("kingdom_name", string_of_pickled_kingdom ). Reverse for loading. See this answer for more on encoding and decoding pickled object strings.
